# 800 speed memory into 1066

Tags: memory

Can you place lower speed RAM into higher slots?

I had a motherboard fail and from my research I can stick a AM3 into an AM3+ slot, but so far no luck with an AM3+ that supports 800 speed RAM.

Comment: You need to refer to your motherboard specification for accepted RAM Speed.

Comment: The MOBO takes 1066 at the least. So I was just curious as to if you could still use lower.

Comment: Some people say that I can be done and motherboard will automatically throttle down to appropriate speed, I never done it my self. So I can't speak to how reliable this setup is going to be.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, DDR2-800 will not work, DDR3-800 might work but is very uncommon.  Typically, it has to be equal or higher than the FSB of your processor.